# Could someone ELI5 how to allow a method to take both a string and an object as parameter?

Tags: java

The following pseudo isn't what I'm currently working on, I just want to know different ways to approach.

1. If I create two classes that work with each other to allow a user to find out information.

```
Main: 

Sport myfavorite = new Sport();
myfavorite.setSport("Hockey"); // works fine for me


Athlete lebron = new Athlete();
lebron.setName("Lebron");
lebron.setSport("Basketball"); // my trouble is here

/* Answer I'm expecting here is if I S.o.p(lebron), I would get his name and sport. */

1st Class (Sport)

setSport(String s); // method works fine if you just call method straight from Sport class

2nd Class (Athlete)

setName(String a);
setSport(Sport newSport); // way in which to get this method to function correctly? method only takes in 
                          // object, so when I feed it a String, it's giving me a conversion error.
```

2. My issue is understanding the concept of how a method that takes in an object is supposed to also take in a String.

Big issue here: I need to know without using classes outside the two classes I would use within each class to give the user info intended in output.

I've been scratching my head at this idea for way too long than I probably should, so examples of different ways to make this work would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for the assistance in advance and I hope to hear from anyone soon.

Comment: Please code this in java. And what does ELI5 mean?

Comment: ELI5 means: explain like I'm five. It's a reference to reddit. Sorry for not writing entire code, just thought this was more of a concept based question. The question could be used for several different scenarios, which is why I wasn't specific to one single way to write each class.

Comment: Also, Mr. Kumar just answered my question for me. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

setSport in Sport class takes argument as String but in Athlete class, this takes Sport class reference. You are just confused just because of same name of method.

You have not written the code, but you code might be like this

```
class Sport {

    private String sport;// your confusion is here due to same name, type of this "String"

    public Sport(){

    }

    public String getSport() {
        return sport;
    }

    public void setSport(String sport) { // it will take String ref
        this.sport = sport;
    }
}


class Athlete{
    private String name;
    private Sport sport; // your confusion is here due to same name, type of this "Sport"

    public Athlete(){

    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Sport getSport() {
        return sport;
    }
    public void setSport(Sport sport) { // it will take Sport ref
        this.sport = sport;
    }


}
```

For further clarification please read this https:**//www.edureka.co/blog/instance-variable-in-java/**

Comment: Could you possibly use private Sport newSport; in the Athlete class? It was a requirement for a specific job I had a while ago and wasn't able to understand why I wasn't able to. Thank you for your detailed explanation. While I'm waiting for your answer, I'll go ahead and try out what you have given me so far to try and understand the concept.

Comment: Also, the classes would not be in the same file location. They would have to reference each other from different file locations. So class Sport would be in its own file location, and class Athlete would be in its own file location. Don't know if that would make any bit of difference.

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you're saying. Thank you so much!